# Ansible: Retrieve Data from inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I need to retrieve the IP of bob_server from the inventory file. I am not clear as to what combination to use in `filter`, `lookup`, and `when`? Depending on the inventory file`bob_server` and `alice_server` names can change, but `app_type` won't change. My playbook logic is obviously wrong, Can someone guide me the correct way to fetch IP address when `app_type = bob`

My current Inventory file:

```
---
all:
  hosts:
  children:
    bob_server:
      hosts: 10.192.2.6
      vars:
        app_type: bob
    alice_server:
      hosts: 10.192.2.53
      vars:
        app_type: alice
```

My Playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  name: Retrive data
  tasks:
    - name: Set Ambari IP
      set_fact:
        ambariIP: "{{ lookup('hosts', children) }}"
      when: "hostvars[app_type] == 'bob'"
```

Comment: Your inventory file is invalid. Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) and fix it. Moreover you seem to confuse the concept of group and host. This is explained in documentation too. Once all this is fixed, you won't need any fancy lookup: using `inventory_hostname` or `ansible_host` (depending on how you name your hosts) will give you the expected data.

Comment: Yes, the concept of group and host is confusing. But, no, the inventory is not invalid. See below, ``ansible-inventory -i hosts-01 --list`` works fine. No reason to close, I think. It's a good example of how (not) to use the (still valid) [YAML inventory format](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups).

Answer (score 1):

Given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts-01
---
all:
  hosts:
  children:
    bob_server:
      hosts: 10.192.2.6
      vars:
        app_type: bob
    alice_server:
      hosts: 10.192.2.53
      vars:
        app_type: alice
```

The simple option is using `ansible-inventory`, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: ansible-inventory -i hosts-01 --list
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        my_inventory: "{{ result.stdout|from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_inventory.bob_server.hosts
```

gives

```yaml
  my_inventory.bob_server.hosts:
  - 10.192.2.6
```

---

If you want to parse the file on your own read it into a dictionary and flatten the paths, e.g. (install ansible.utils `ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.utils`)

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: hosts-01
        name: my_hosts
    - set_fact:
        my_paths: "{{ lookup('ansible.utils.to_paths', my_hosts) }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_paths
```

gives

```yaml
  my_paths:
    all.children.alice_server.hosts: 10.192.2.53
    all.children.alice_server.vars.app_type: alice
    all.children.bob_server.hosts: 10.192.2.6
    all.children.bob_server.vars.app_type: bob
    all.hosts: null
```

Now select the keys ending `bob_server.hosts`

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        bob_server_hosts: "{{ my_paths|
                              dict2items|
                              selectattr('key', 'match', '^.*bob_server\\.hosts$')|
                              items2dict }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  bob_server_hosts:
    all.children.bob_server.hosts: 10.192.2.6
```

and select the IPs

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        bob_server_ips: "{{ bob_server_hosts.values()|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  bob_server_ips:
  - 10.192.2.6
```

---

The inventory is missing the concept of groups. See [Inventory basics: formats, hosts, and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups). Usually, the value of `children` is a group of hosts. In this inventory, the value of `children` is the single host. This is conceptually wrong but still valid, .e.g

```yaml
- hosts: bob_server
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts-01 playbook.ym
  ...
TASK [debug] ****************************************************
ok: [10.192.2.6] =>
  inventory_hostname: 10.192.2.6
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the problem in my case is inventory is dynamic. Also, bob_server and Alice_server are also dynamic, only `app_type`  is consistent